# Is there a way to use Gradle API within a Maven build Environment?

Tags: java, maven, gradle

I'm building a maven project that retrieves the dependency lists from other gradle projects.  ( using java. not the mvn console)

I want to use getDependencies() function from Gradle API like below.

```
import org.gradle.api.artifacts.Configuration;
import org.gradle.api.artifacts.dsl.DependencyHandler;

DependencyHandler dependencies = project.getDependencies();
```

But it looks like Gradle API can be used only in Gradle build environments.

I added gradle-core in my pom.xml like below but it doesn't seem to have the api's I need to retrieve the dependencies

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.gradle</groupId>
  <artifactId>gradle-core</artifactId>
  <version>2.2.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Is there a way to use Gradle API within a Maven build Environment?

Comment: Where exactly do you want to read dependencies? Inside a Java programm? Inside a Maven plugin?

Comment: @JFMeier I want to read dependencies inside a Java program~

Comment: From where do you read the gradle projects? From git? From a maven repository?

Answer (score 0):

Technically, it *may* be possible since Gradle at its core is just Java. However, you would need construct the Gradle project, construct subprojects, invoke various lifecycle methods, and many many more things Gradle does in order to correctly create a [`Project`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Project.html) instance.

With that said, it's far 'easier' to just invoke Gradle through the command via [`ProcessBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) to get a list of dependencies with the [`dependencies`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/viewing_debugging_dependencies.html#sec:listing_dependencies) task. Something like:

```
ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder();
processBuilder.command("gradlew", "dependencies");
Process process = processBuilder.start();

try (var reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()))) {
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        // Do something with the output
    }
}
```

If you have access to the Gradle projects, then it's by far significantly easier to create a [custom Gradle task](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/custom_tasks.html) that creates a file (JSON or whatever format you need) of all the dependencies and whatever else you need. This way you can use the example above to call the custom task, then consume the file in a easily readable format in Maven.